# Uploading issue in Android Play Store

Tags: android, uploading

I am having an issue while uploading an Android app on the play store. While I am trying to upload it says

> your app has been suspended due to using intellectual

Well actually I had developed an android app for my college so, I just want to upload it, can you help me how to upload a college app.

Comment: `impersonation policy` ??

Comment: `your app has been suspended`  then you can't obviously upload an update.

Answer (score 4):

If Google suspended your App means check

1. Privacy Policy
2. you are taking information without knowing to the user in the background
3. check your app reading user messages in a proper way?
4. Read 
   a. https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/device-network-abuse/

   b. https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

   c. https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

Comment: thanks for the reply but I was asking that how to upload an app that is a brand app or something like that! not a normal app...